# i want static variables in c++ and other languages.getting error " `total_no_of_customers': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass'"

Tags: ruby

this is my code in which i want to use static ruby variable. which shows total no of objects created a an time

```
!/usr/bin/ruby

class Customer
    @total_customers = 0
    def initialize(id, name, addr)
        @cust_id = id
        @cust_name = name
        @cust_addr = addr
    end

    def display_details()
        puts "Customer id #@cust_id"
        puts "Customer name #@cust_name"
        puts "Customer address #@cust_addr"
    end

    def total_no_of_customers() 
        @total_customers += 1
        puts "Total number of customers: #@to**strong text**tal_customers"
    end
end

# Create Objects
cust1 = Customer.new("1", "Ali", "Johar Town, Lahore")
cust2 = Customer.new("2", "Umer", "Farid Town, Sahiwal")

#Call Methods
cust1.total_no_of_customers()
cust2.total_no_of_customers()
```

Comment: There is no question in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
!/usr/bin/ruby

class Customer
      @@total_customers = 0
      def initialize(id, name, addr)
          @cust_id = id
          @cust_name = name
          @cust_addr = addr
          @@total_customers +=1;
      end

      def display_details()
          puts "Customer id #{@cust_id}"
          puts "Customer name #{@cust_name}"
          puts "Customer address #{@cust_addr}"
      end

      def total_no_of_customers() 
          puts "Total number of customers: #{@@total_customers}"
      end
    end
```

You need a class variable which is defined by using @@ and the name of the variable. 
Every time a new object of type customer is being instantiated this variable will increase by one therefore you should increase this counter on the initialize method.

The @@ creates a class variable which will be shared with all instances of Customer.